# Java IO FileNotFoundException after converting file name toURL()

Tags: java, jython

Here is the Jython code (although this may not be a Jython-specific issue)...

```
file_name = "Manifest.ttl"
file_url = File(file_name).toURL()
f = File(file_url.toString())
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   file:/home/james/projects/wordnet/wordnet30/rdf/Manifest.ttl (No such
>   file or directory)

Comment: Is the file present in that location? I would assume not. Where is it actually present?

Comment: Yes -- the toURL() method converted it to the the full path based on just the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) to the rescue:

> Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string
>   into an abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string,
>   then the result is the empty abstract pathname.
>
> Parameters:
>       pathname - A pathname string

The File constructor takes an abstract path name as argument, not the toString representation of a URL.

Besides, `toURL` is deprecated. You might use `toURI`, and reconstruct the file with this URI.

Answer (score 0):

toURL() adds the file:// prefix that a proper URL/URI requires.  Clearly the File constructor doesn't check and remove this prefix, so it's looking for a file called "file://..." instead of where you want it to look "/home/james/...".

Comment: Thanks. I was getting another error by the RDF library about a file being an invalid URL so I was trying to give it a valid URL.