# java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/xxxxx

Tags: java

I'm trying to edit an xml file from java code . here's the method :

```
public static void changeReportPath(String reportPath){

      DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
      try {
    docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    File file = new File(reportPath);
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(reportPath);

    // Get the root element
    Node root = doc.getFirstChild();
    // Get the staff element by tag name directly
    NodeList parameter = doc.getElementsByTagName("defaultValueExpression");

    NodeList defaultValueExpression =parameter.item(0).getChildNodes();

        defaultValueExpression.item(0).setTextContent('"'+"/home/amira/work/"+'"');

    // write the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(reportPath));


    transformer.transform(source, result);


      } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (SAXException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (TransformerException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
      }


}
```

Here's the method invocation :

```
 Utilities.changeReportPath("/home/amira/xx/runtime/uploads/report/project/myfile.jrxml");
```

Here's the error log :

---

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/amira/xx/runtime/uploads/report/project/DEVFACCOA.jrxml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:70)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:235)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:278)
    at com.kopimap.utilities.Utilities.changeReportPath(Utilities.java:205)
    at com.example.kopimapreportgeneration.KopimapreportgenerationUI$ReportUploader.uploadSucceeded(KopimapreportgenerationUI.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:167)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:968)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Upload.fireUploadSuccess(Upload.java:811)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Upload$1.streamingFinished(Upload.java:1070)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.streamToReceiver(FileUploadHandler.java:554)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.handleFileUploadValidationAndData(FileUploadHandler.java:419)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.doHandleSimpleMultipartFileUpload(FileUploadHandler.java:382)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.FileUploadHandler.handleRequest(FileUploadHandler.java:267)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1329)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:236)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I found this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247427/java-io-filenotfoundexception-after-converting-file-name-tourl)

So i change this line :

```
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file.toURI().toString());
```

But the problem persists

Comment: I can only assume that you check that the file actually exist? The file that can't be found is `DEVFACCOA.jrxml` and in your invocation example it says `myfile.jrxml`. Not sure how Jasper file looks like but maybe it refer to a file you missed?

Comment: no no i test it twice , the file exists

Comment: Could it be a permission problem where your application do not have permissions to access to the file?

Answer (score 1):

Use file instead of URI:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(reportPath);
```

Replace it with:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
```

According to Java Doc:

> `public class FileNotFoundException extends IOException`
>
> Signals that an attempt to open the file denoted by a specified
> pathname has failed.
>
> This exception will be thrown by the FileInputStream,
> FileOutputStream, and RandomAccessFile constructors when a file with
> the specified pathname does not exist. It will also be thrown by these
> constructors if the file does exist but for some reason is
> inaccessible, for example when an attempt is made to open a read-only
> file for writing.

So you either don't have the file or don't have needed permissions

Comment: Thank you but the problem persists

Comment: Then probably it's permission problem. Try this: chmod u+rw,g+rw,o+rw for your file

Comment: i tried this   Document doc = docBuilder.parse("file://home/amira/kopiMap/runtime/uploads/report/TestReport/DEVFACCOA.jrxml");

Comment: But it gives this error java.net.UnknownHostException: home
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
 at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:157)

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure but think you'r problem is to define the path . i mean you should for example add your project root path to your file address .